# How to make Acrobat show entire Spread instead of one side per spread

Tags: adobe-acrobat

I am creating a PDF from a file in Acrobat and the spreads are correct and everything but I want my entire spread to show in the page thumbnail box, but it only shows one side of a spread per page, is there a way to make the view go to full spread instead of half a page spread?

Answer (score 1):

Page *thumbnails* generally show to signature in the PDF. In other words, if you exported to PDF as single pages, then the thumbnails will show single pages. You can alter how the main window displays content by choosing `File > Properties` in Acrobat and clicking the `Initial View` tab. There, you can set the main display to be two-up if desired:

[image]

This won't alter the page thumbnails though. If you want the thumbnails to be two-up, you need to export the PDF as spreads rather than single pages.

Answer (score 0):

No this doesn't display spreads in thumbnails. Exporting as spreads gives you only one page number not both. That is what the question is. I'm making edits to page spreads in indesign and it leads to having to scroll to the bottom of the page to keep track of the correct page numbers. Very inconvenient.